# Route to Software Engineering

Tags: software-engineering

wondering if anyone can give me some advice. I’m 17 and just about to leave high school and Morgan Stanley have offered me a job as an analyst and said they’d pay for me to get a BSc degree in Software development from a good uni (Strathclyde) and if I do well I’ll progress to a tech associate in 4 years. But I’ve also got an offer to study a MSc in Computing Science at a good uni (St Andrews) and I don’t know what is better to get into software engineering - with your experience in the tech industry what do you think would be better long term?

Comment: Sorry; career advice is out of scope for this site.  We focus on technical questions about computer science.